# getting error messege: A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified

Tags: linux, cuda, nsight

also getting: 
make: *** [main.o] Error 255

I am really new to this
I am using nsight for linux with cuda toolkit 5

I added this two lines 
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
in .bashrc becuase in .profile file it didnt seems to have an effect,  and there was no .bash_profile file

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there was a number of issue in Nsight Eclipse Edition 5.0 preview release that would cause this error (we fixed all such bugs we found).

Please provide more information:

1. Does your workspace path, project name and/or source file path have any spaces?
2. Do you see the same issue with a simple bitreverse application (you can create a bitreverse project from New CUDA C/C++ Project wizard using "CUDA Runtime Project" template?
3. Do you have source files with extensions other then cu?
4. Can you paste your make output?

Feel free to contact CUDA tools team directly by posting to cudatools@nvidia.com

Comment: I have one source file which have .cpp extension. Does it have to have .cu extension ? because I saw in one of the demonstrations of Sara Tariq that she use cpp extension for the cuda files..when I put .cu extension , nothing seems to happend when I run the program
Actually I am trying to make the vector edition program , the one with diffrent blocks

Comment: update: I downloaded update for ubuntu, and suddenly the program do printf the correct result, but now when I launch nsight , I get this:
Error: API mismatch: the NVIDIA kernel module has version 302.06.03,
but this NVIDIA driver component has version 295.49.  Please make
sure that the kernel module and all NVIDIA driver components
have the same version.

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, there was a bug in Nsight 5.0 preview release that would sometimes break builds when there were both cu and cpp files in the source folders. It will be fix in upcoming 5.0 RC release.
2. For the second problem - you need to install compatible graphics driver.

Comment: ok, I reinstalled devdriver_5.0_linux_64_302.06.03 , and now I have same thing-when puting .cu extension the file compiles but nothing happens when it runs. when putting .cpp extension I get this messege:
A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified

Comment: cuda runtime project seems to work
I have 1 source file
make output when using .cu extension:

**** Build of configuration Debug for project mc ****

make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

**** Build Finished ****

Comment: this is the output when I use .cpp extension:

**** Build of configuration Debug for project mc ****

make all 
Building file: ../mc.cpp
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -odir "" -M -o "mc.d" "../mc.cpp"
nvcc --compile -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_20,code=compute_20 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -o  "mc.o" "../mc.cpp" "../mc.cpp"
nvcc fatal   : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified
make: *** [mc.o] Error 255

**** Build Finished ****

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known issue in a preview release and we have no walkaround other then changing file extensions. This bug will be fixed in upcoming 5.0 RC release.

Comment: but what should I do? 
There is only one source file , its extension is .cu, the nsight ide  dont give me any error when I build it, but the program doesn't output anything to console. if I add getchar() before the invocation of my Cuda code then I get the output till the getchar(). but if I put the getchar() after the invocation of the cuda function, I dont get anything in console.

Comment: Nsight compiles the code exactly the same way you would compile from the command line (note that it does debug build with -g -G switches by default). Do you see this application behaviour when you run the application from the command line or in the debugger? Make sure you check CUDA Runtime calls return codes.